# How to make clickable text

Tags: color, text-decorations

How can I make clickable words colored?

For example, if you could look here in the abstract on page-v, http://mural.maynoothuniversity.ie/4213/1/KumarShravan_PhDThesis2012.pdf

And, what color has he used? Is that blue? I would like to make an abstract with a similar style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using the `hyperref` package. The default links are red boxes but this can be changed.
In your preamble put

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue}
```

You can also use any other colour that LaTeX knows or use a package like `xcolor` to use any RGB colour.
Note that `hyperref` should almost always be the last package that you include except for specific pacakges which should go after it.

Then, say you want to link to a section, where you define that section include a `\label`:

```
\section{Test Section}\label{sec:test section}
```

And later in the document when you want a link put

```
\ref{sec:test section}
```

and it will automatically be a link.
`hyperref` also has facilities for urls and other links. Check out the package documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Hello, Could you please tell me what is the color at page vii? https://d2k0ddhflgrk1i.cloudfront.net/Websections/TU%20Delft%20Huisstijl/dissertation.pdf

Comment: Hex: `00B9F2`, RGB `0, 186, 242`, using `color` or `xcolor` packages you can define this colour as `\define{myBlue}{RGB}{0, 186, 242}` and then use `myBlue` in place of `blue` above. To find this colour I simply screen shotted the document and used a colour selector in MS Paint to find the hex value and then googled hex to RGB, although you can just use the hex (`xcolor` only) with `\definecolor{HTML}{myBlue}{00B9F2}`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The blue color you are looking for is something similar to RGB `23,111,193` (retrieved with the Eyedropper tool of WPS Writer).
Here is a minimal working examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{23,111,193}
\usepackage{acronym}
  \renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=myblue,
     urlcolor=myblue,
     %citecolor=myblue,
   }
  
\acrodef{CTAN}{Comprehensive \TeX\ Archive Network}

\begin{document}

This is an acronym: \acs{CTAN}

See \autoref{sec:title}

See \url{http:\\www.ctan.org}

\section{The first section} \label{sec:title}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Hello, Could you please tell me what is the color at page vii? https://d2k0ddhflgrk1i.cloudfront.net/Websections/TU%20Delft%20Huisstijl/dissertation.pdf

Comment: Try this RGB 0,185,242

Comment: Thanks so much, could you please tell me what RGB combination to get this color? https://ibb.co/NY0MdJy